# Delay onComplete() in Observable

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I am doing something like this:

```
return Observable.zip(
    Observable.interval(0, MOVE_LENGTH_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
    Observable.fromIterable(mySuperNiceArrayList),
        new BiFunction<Long, ItemTest, ItemTest>() {
            @Override
            public ItemTest apply(@NonNull Long aLong, @NonNull ItemTest itemTest) throws Exception {
                  return itemTest;
            }
        }
)
```

The problem that I have is that immediately after the last item is emitted, onComplete is called. Is there a way to postpone/delay the call of onComplete method?

Hacky solution is to add one more element to ArrayList and to ignore it in onNext().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concat the *entire zip* with an empty `Observable` delayed:

```
return Observable.zip(
    Observable.interval(0, MOVE_LENGTH_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
    Observable.fromIterable(mySuperNiceArrayList),
        new BiFunction<Long, ItemTest, ItemTest>() {
            @Override
            public ItemTest apply(@NonNull Long aLong, 
                    @NonNull ItemTest itemTest) throws Exception {
                return itemTest;
            }
        }
).concatWith(Observable.<ItemTest>empty()
                 .delay(MOVE_LENGTH_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

**Edit** the delay should happen after the zip.

Comment: Each time Rx related question comes up I wait for Karnok to answer :-)

Comment: I am getting following error: `concatWith io.reactivex.ObservableSource<? extends ItemTest> can not be applied to to io.reactivex.ObservableSource<java.lang.Object>`.
I know why it's happening but don't know how to fix it. Is there a way to cast Observable?

Comment: Sometimes you have to explicitly add `<ItemTest>` to method calls. See the updated answer.

Comment: It should be working but it doesn't. Is it possible that BiFunction is not being applied on null objects?

Comment: Maybe you imported the wrong `BiFunction`? You need the `io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction`. Also sometimes the error message hides the fact that you have the wrong method call or a nonexistent method call.

Comment: It works with `.concatWith(Observable.just(new ItemTest())` as expected, but then I can just add one more element to the array. I would like a little cleaner solution.

Comment: And I have `io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction` imported.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/edc646de9a5673d610e51ac3b13b931d) compiles fine for me.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding. It's compiling for me also, but it's not working. I am still getting this response: 
`item->delay->item->delay ... ->item->onComplete()`
There is no delay after the last item.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about the prefetching in zip which realizes your source immediately. See the updated answer; the concatWith could be placed outside.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.